# backbone.js event listeners can only be attached to child elements of the "el" property

Tags: backbone.js

I am following the backbone tutorial http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/ and in the paragraph **Listening for events** there is the following phrase:

> Remember that event listeners can only be attached to child elements of the "el" property.

and then they are doing the following code:

```
<script type="text/template" id="search_template">
  <label>Search</label>
  <input type="text" id="search_input" />
  <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
</script>

<div id="search_container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {} );
            this.$el.html( template );
        },
        events: {
            "click input[type=button]": "doSearch"
        },
        doSearch: function( event ){
            // Button clicked, you can access the element that was clicked with event.currentTarget
            alert( "Search for " + $("#search_input").val() );
        }
    });

    var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
</script>
```

But the el property is `#search _container` which does not have children at all. And they are applying the listener to the `input` which is the child of `search_template`

I think I misunderstood something, because it does not make any sense for me. Can anyone right me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When SearchView.render is called `#search _container` will have children , the content of the template defined in `#search_template`

Answer (score 0):

In backbone.js events are delegated, in fact we don't care the HTML is not yet rendered because events will automatically be attached when the view is rendered.